# .htaccess redirect

Tags: .htaccess

I want to redirect http://localhost/xyz index.php.  This index.php is in the /var/www/xyz/. I have a specific reason to do this.

RewriteRule http://localhost/xyz index.php does not work, I have no idea why

Thanks
Jean

Comment: What would you like to redirect to /xyz/index.php?

Comment: I also have RewriteRule $ frame.php, what this will do is localhost/xyz/e would redirect to frame.php. but /xyz/ will not go to index.php.  Now this seems stupid, if you can straighten it out

Answer (score 1):

Apply the rules to the path, not to the url (=leave http://localhost).

```
RewriteRule /xyz /index.php
```

This rule will also apply to /bla/xyz and to /xyzabc. Even to /blah/xyzabc. The first parameter can be changed to forbid this:

```
RewriteRule ^/xyz$ /index.php
```

If you want to learn more about rewriterules, I think the cheatsheet would be useful for you: http://www.addedbytes.com/cheat-sheets/mod_rewrite-cheat-sheet/ And maybe google for some rewriterule examples.

Comment: I also have RewriteRule $ frame.php, what this will do is http://localhost/xyz/e would redirect to frame.php. but /xyz/ will not go to index.php